# Парсинг selenium python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Мне нужно спарсить часть информации из тега а. Я знаю между какими элементами ( символами) он заключен. Как прописать вывод только этой информации[image]

```
  img = str(a.get_attribute('onclick'))
            img = img[img.find('"{temp:{x:') + 4:img.find('",')]
            print(f'URL image: {img}')
```

Что нужно дописать, чтобы выводилась только ссылка?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: тут телепатов очень мало. Какая ссылка?

Comment: Выделил повторно.

Comment: а код из вопроса что выводит?

Comment: URL image:    urn showPhoto('-159533568_457373498', 'wall-159533568_1939035', {"temp":{"x":"https:\/\/sun1.userapi.com\/sun1-92\/s\/v1\/ig2\/Gw3cbjhk-XN8q7yKlTzbbztQAEhZgJmh6Y5Da53rOJRNoNrOPnBdOG4CVDxBs8gsz3yR7nzNCGd9nBCdXqK94Eb3.jpg?size=604x437&quality=95&type=album

Comment: помог, так помог

Answer (score 0):

```
            img = str(a.get_attribute('onclick'))
            img = img[img.find('"{temp:{x:') + 4:img.find('",')]
            img = img[img.find(":{")+7:]
            img = img.replace('\/', '\\')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]